# PHPStan don't see proper ObjectManager for Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpstan

I try improve my code with PHPStan.
I already install:

- [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan)
- [Doctrine extensions for PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine)
- [PHPStan PHPUnit extensions and rules](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-phpunit)
- [PHPStan Symfony Framework extensions and rules](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-symfony)

Here my phpstan.neon:

```
includes:
  - vendor/phpstan/phpstan/conf/config.levelmax.neon
  - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-symfony/extension.neon
  - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/extension.neon
  - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/rules.neon
  - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-phpunit/extension.neon
  - vendor/phpstan/phpstan-phpunit/rules.neon
parameters:
  paths:
    - %currentWorkingDirectory%/src
    - %currentWorkingDirectory%/tests
  symfony:
    container_xml_path: '%currentWorkingDirectory%/var/cache/dev/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml'
  autoload_directories:
    - %currentWorkingDirectory%/tests
```

Also I have test with calling next functions:

```
$kernel = static::bootKernel();
$doctrine = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
$doctrine->getManager()->getConfiguration();
$doctrine->getManager()->getEventManager();
```

And PHPStan complain on that:

```
Call to an undefined method Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager::getConfiguration().
Call to an undefined method Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager::getEventManager().
```

I researched that `$doctrine->getManager()` I have `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface` that extend `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager` but PHPStan think that I have `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager`

How to tell to PHPStan that `$doctrine->getManager()` is `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface`?

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

1. add a inline PHPDoc (works anywhere):

```php
/** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface */
$doctrine = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
```

2. use assert (works only in tests):

```php
$doctrine = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
self::assertInstanceOf(EntityManagerInterface::class, $doctrine);
```